# Overlapping calls to single function, want each to wait a second before executing function but not force all to wait

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am familiar with the `time` module to sleep the main thread in Python. However, what I'm trying to accomplish is something like

```
def calc():
    '''
    Currently sleeps main thread
    Want to sleep single calc() call and allow other asynchronous to occur
    '''
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(10000):
        pass

# multiple asynchronous overlapping calls of calc()
```

I'm thinking I need to use the `threading` package to call `calc()` so `time.sleep(1)` only effects the individual thread. However, I'm also considering using the `multiprocessing` module but I'm not 100% on this.

Could someone provide some guidance on how they would approach this?

Comment: Seems like `calc()` could have an (optional) argument that tells it whether to `sleep()` or not.

Comment: IMO, multiprocessing gives you greater control on parallel execution. Also, sleep will make any thread/process that calls this function to wait/sleep for the specified time. Unless you are in danger of a deadlock situation over shared resources, this function is good to go